# What's the best way of setting up these complicated model associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design, associations

I want to add commenting to my application so that an owner of a video can choose for that video the number of commenting columns/forms side-by-side and add a title to each column, and then users can comment on one or more of the columns.

I'm thinking of setting up a VideoComment model whose table looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------
id | video_id | user_id | comment_id
```

Then videos would have a has_many through association with comments through VideoComment. Also, users would have a has_many through association with each comments and videos through VideoComment.

To support the multiple columns, I'm thinking of having Comment have a habtm association with another model CommentColumns.

Comment will look like this:

```
-----------------------------
id | body
```

CommentColumns will look like this:

```
------------------------
id | title
```

And the join table between the comment and commentColumn will be CommentMatching:

```
------------------------------
comment_id | comment_column_id
```

My first question is... Am I on the right track, or am I significantly far off?

My second question is... what are all the possible combinations for accessing the different data associations in my controller?

PS. Don't be shy! Please ask me any questions if you would like me to clarify something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend something more along the lines of how a forum works for what you're describing:

- A User has_many videos and comments
- A video has_many topics
- A topic belongs_to video and has_many comments
- Comments belong_to user and topic

Then your associations are somewhat simple, you don't really even need any HABTM type associations.

What are all the possible combinations? Loads, but here are a few examples:

```
#Create a video
@user.videos.create(...attributes...)

#Create a topic
@video.topics.create(...attributes...)

#Create a comment
@topic.comments.create(...attributes...)

#Find all comments from a user
@user.comments

#Find all comments from a particular topics
@topic.comments

#Find all comments from a particular user on a particular topic
@topic.comments.where(:user=>foo)
```

Hope that makes sense.

-EDIT-

There are different ways you could find all the comments for a particular video, the question is what do you need them for?

If you just want to show them in your view, the simplest thing would be something like this (in HAML):

```
- for topic in @video.topics do
  = topic.title
  - for comment in topic.comments do
    = comment.body
```

To return them all as a query I suppose you could do something like...

```
# untested
Comment.joins(:topics).where('topics.video_id' => video.id)
```

You could do the same for users comments per video, or you could just add an association where comment belongs_to video. One warning, though... --edited out, see below---

-EDIT-

Ok, I take it back, I remembered my own app wrong. There are no "gotchas" that I can recall about associating comments to both a video and a topic, so the easiest thing would just be to set comments to belong_to videos as well. Be sure and test the associations though so you don't get `video = nil` in your records. I didn't test this but as I recall building through the video like `@video.topics.first.comments.create(:attributes)` actually doesn't create the video association, only the topic association. I think I had to do something more like:

```
@topic.comments.create(...attributes..., :video=>@topic.video)
```

Test that and be sure.

Now that I looked back at my own code what I was remembering trouble with was when I needed to build a nested relationship where an object could belong to a parent of the same class AND a parent container. IE: Comments could have nested replies, so comments belong to topics and also belong to other comments. THAT is what raised trouble. Comments belonging to one topic and one video is fine.

Sorry for the mental lapse :)

After you've got your association just do...

```
@video.comments.where(:user=>some_user)
```

..and you'll get all the comments on a video from a particular user.

Comment: Your setup makes sense except for one thing that confuses me: A video has many topics, and a topic has many comments, but I imagine the comments like a table with each horizontal comment spreading across a multitude of vertical topics, and so wouldn't a comment have many topics? Or is each comment actually just one block and not an entire horizontal row?

Comment: Also, how would you get all of a users comments for a specific video?

Comment: Something like `@video.topics.comments.where(:user_id => X)`?

Comment: RE: Getting all comments -- see above. RE: the other...  what??? You said the user leaves multiple comment columns with a title, ie: "What did you think of the main actor?","What is your favorite scene in the movie?", "What do you think of the soundtrack?" -- ie the user is asking questions right? And each comment is supposed to correspond to one of those *topics*, right? So, then each comment belongs_to a particular question, or *topic*... (see below)

Comment: If you want to show them each as columns that's fine, just set up your view that way. There's no reason the layout of your page should determine the layout of your database.

Comment: ahh ok got it... that makes perfect sense. Thanks Andrew!

Comment: OK I'll take your word for it and not add a direct association between videos and comments. Would you mind showing me an example of accessing a user's comments per video? I'm having trouble with this... thanks!

Comment: @Justin -- ok, I looked back at my own code to see how I did it, and I realized I remembered what gave me problems incorrectly. See above.

Comment: I agree with Andrew, avoid habtm, it's more trouble than it's worth and often changes later when additional info is added.  definetly use a good form generator like formtastic, or, even better, simple_form to maintain the relationshops without tons of code.

Comment: when you do the where call: `.where(:user=>some_user)` what is "some_user" supposed to be? Could you use `.where(:user_id => X)`?

Comment: also, since I'm going to have the creation of topics and comments on the video show view, should I have any nested resources or virtual attributes? Or can I do without them?

Comment: @Michael simple_form looks pretty nice... I was originally thinking of having separate forms for each topic, but now I just think I'm going to use simple_form's built in association handling to use a single form.

Comment: @Justin: 'some_user' is a user object, like 'current_user' or 'User.find(1)' or something. As for the rest, it's up to you, but I would probably just put a single form for adding a topic and let the user submit it multiple times to get multiple topics. Make it an ajax form and it'll be seamless. I don't think you need any nested resources or virtual attributes, probably just a hidden field with the ID of the topic you want to associate a new comment to. You'll already have the video ID as params[:id] in your controller.

Comment: @Andrew don't you think nested resources would be easier though in my case? apparently it's not a good idea to nest a resource within a nested resource though... so perhaps I could nest topic and comment inside video at the same level?

Comment: @Justin: Really, if you're not displaying the resource by itself there isn't much reason to use nested resources. The major reason to do nested resources is to get the sexy URLs that they generate, but working with nested resources is somewhat inconvenient otherwise. I wouldn't do it for this. I *would* do it if you have something like a profile that belongs to a user and that the user will want to be able to browse to directly. IE: The url `/videos/12/topics/3471/comments/14212` is pretty worthless, but `/users/214/profile` isn't. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Andrew yea that makes perfect sense, I'm going to use nested attributes for topics and comments... seems like that's the standard convention for what i'm trying to do